# how to implement Loader widget in magento2

Tags: magento2, jquery, widgets

I want to implement loader widget in magento 2,
In my form i have placed one button

```
<div style="display:inline; float:right;  width:100%; margin-bottom:5px;">
    <button style="" class="scalable go" type="submit" id="button1"><span>Do some action</span></button>
</div>
```

When i click this button i want to call url (frontName/Controller/Action). While this action performing i want to show loader widget.

Comment: Widget initialization is described in M2 devdocs:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html

Answer (score 45):

It's impressively simple when used inside a JS file loaded via Require JS (All/most your scripts should be so I won't go into detail about that):

```
 $('body').trigger('processStart');
```

And to remove it

```
$('body').trigger('processStop');
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: thanks man you saved me up-voted

Answer (score 20):

Magento2 has [loader widget](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_loader.html).

Simples way to use it with ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
    ...// ajax setting,
    showLoader: true, // enable loader
    context: jqueryElementorSelector // element that will be coverer by loader, default body, optional
}).than(...)
```

Also you can use it by self

```
<div data-role="pannel" data-mage-init='{"loader": {}}'>
     content
</div>
```

and in JS

```
$('[data-role="pannel"]').trigger('show.loader'); // or .mage('loader', 'show')
....
$('[data-role="pannel"]').trigger('hide.loader');
```

Comment: I am using `showLoader: true`  inside the `$.ajax` setting. I am getting the following error in the console:  `loader.js:210 Expected to start loader but did not find one in the dom` Any idea why this might be? Do I have to add a loader element to the DOM manually? I am using a custom theme, perhaps I removed a block containing the default loader?

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to show loading icon in Magento use script:

**To show loader:**

```
jQuery('body').loader('show');
```

or use:

```
var body = $('body').loader();
body.loader('show');
```

or

```
$('body').trigger('processStart');
```

**To hide loader:**

```
var body = $('body').loader();
body.loader('hide');
```

OR

```
jQuery('body').loader('hide');
```

OR

```
jQuery('body').loader('destroy');
```

OR

```
var body = $('body').loader();
body.loader('destroy');
```

OR

```
$('body').trigger('processStop');
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to call loader on non-ajax call

Temporary solution: you can use on submit or any other event: 
$( 'body' ).loader('show');

https://minhducnho.wordpress.com/2016/11/23/magento2-show-default-loader-in-magento/

but i guess this is not magento way to call loader widget on non-ajax call , I had same issue so implemented it as temporary solution.