# How to add loader untill the image not ready on page load

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

I want to show the image in particular div.

I want to show the empty div . if the img src is ready , then it display the img tag in particular div

How to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$("#img").load(function(){
     alert("Image loaded");
});
```

Reference: http://jsfiddle.net/5WFjj/

To display loader for that div, use below code

```
<div data-role="showimage" data-mage-init='{"loader": {}}'>
     Your image
</div>
```

JS would be modified as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('[data-role="showimage"]').trigger('show.loader');
      $("#img").load(function(){
           alert("Image loaded");
           $('[data-role="showimage"]').trigger('hide.loader'); 
      });
});
```

Reference: [how to implement Loader widget in magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76446/how-to-implement-loader-widget-in-magento2)

Comment: how to add loader untill the image is ready...

Comment: In which page do you want to add loader? in product detail page or any other page.

Comment: Please check updated code

Comment: In view page .......

Comment: <div data-role="showimage" data-mage-init='{"loader": {}}'>
    <img id="img" class="main-img" src="http://magento/pub/media/images/sizechart/babydoll.png">
</div>
<script>
    require([
        'jquery'
    ], function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function(){alert("sdfsdf");
            $('[data-role="showimage"]').trigger('show.loader');
            $("#img").load(function(){
                alert("Image loaded");
                $('[data-role="showimage"]').trigger('hide.loader');
            });
        });
    });
</script>

Comment: @khushbu ... its not working

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: its not show this alert ...alert("Image loaded");

Comment: I want to show the empty div . if the img src is ready , then it display the img tag ... how to do this

Comment: I can't find a reliable way to call function when div content changed. but what you can try is hide image until it's src loaded using css and on src load show it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90015/discussion-between-mano-m-and-khushbu).