# Magento2.3: How to put a loader?

Tags: magento2.3, performance, loader

My website is taking too much time to load. When the site is loading, there are chances that the customer to click on the things which is not active yet. So I want to put a loader before the site is active.

In order to put a loader, where I have to update the code?

Comment: dont do this... fix your loading issues.

Comment: @MagenX, Thanks. Yes, I'm fixing that issue. Since our website is under development, I want to show the loader when the site is loading.

Comment: Take a look here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76446/how-to-implement-loader-widget-in-magento2