# How to show loader on custom checkout page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, javascript, ajax, loader, savedata

I have created some steps in magento 2 on saving the data an ajax is fired.
I want to show loader between start and complete process how to i achieve that.

My JS file for saving the data is :

```
define(
[
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/url-builder',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/error-processor',
    'mage/url'
],
function ($, quote, urlBuilder, errorProcessor, urlFormatter) {
'use strict';

return {
    /**
     * Save SimpleNote ibn the quote
     *
     * @param simpleNote
     */
    $('body').trigger('processStart');
    save: function (simpleNote) {
        if (simpleNote) {
            var quoteId = quote.getQuoteId();
            var url;

            url = urlBuilder.createUrl('/carts/mine/set-simple-note', {});

            var payload = {
                cartId: quoteId,
                simpleNote: {
                    simpleNote: simpleNote
                }
            };

            if (!payload.simpleNote.simpleNote) {

                return true;
            }

            var result = true;

            $.ajax({
                url: urlFormatter.build(url),
                data: JSON.stringify(payload),
                global: false,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                type: 'PUT',
                async: false
            }).done(
                function (response) {
                    result = true;
                    $('body').trigger('processStop');
                }
            ).fail(
                function (response) {
                    result = false;
                    errorProcessor.process(response);
                    $('body').trigger('processStop');
                }
            );

            return result;
        }
    }
};
});
```

Comment: I don't see you calling a loader. what have you tried?

Comment: Yes i have added loader in define parameter and added that in $.ajax code like showLoader: true but it doesn't show @PhilippSander

Answer (score 1):

You can show the loader with  `$('body').trigger('processStart');` and hide it with `$('body').trigger('processStop');`.

```
define(
[
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/url-builder',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/error-processor',
    'mage/url'
],
function ($, quote, urlBuilder, errorProcessor, urlFormatter) {
'use strict';

return {
    /**
     * Save SimpleNote ibn the quote
     *
     * @param simpleNote
     */
    save: function (simpleNote) {
        if (simpleNote) {
            var quoteId = quote.getQuoteId();
            var url;

            url = urlBuilder.createUrl('/carts/mine/set-simple-note', {});

            var payload = {
                cartId: quoteId,
                simpleNote: {
                    simpleNote: simpleNote
                }
            };

            if (!payload.simpleNote.simpleNote) {

                return true;
            }

            var result = true;

            $.ajax({
                url: urlFormatter.build(url),
                data: JSON.stringify(payload),
                global: false,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                type: 'PUT',
                async: false,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('body').trigger('processStart');
                }
            }).done(
                function (response) {
                    result = true;
                }
            ).fail(
                function (response) {
                    result = false;
                    errorProcessor.process(response);
                }
            ).always(
                function() {
                    $('body').trigger('processStop');
                }
            );

            return result;
        }
    }
};
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response where should i use that piece of code like after if or on $.ajax({}) @Ben

Comment: You can likely show the loader before your AJAX request and hide it after the AJAX request as you have `async` set to false.

Comment: Like this i have updated in my code is it correct will you please check @Ben

Comment: No that will likely error as you're trying to run a function as a property of an object. I have updated my answer with some code that should work for you.

Comment: I have updated your code but it doesn't show the loader.@Ben

Comment: If you add `console.log('Testing')` in the `beforeSend` and `always` functions do you see the logs?

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Yes on adding console.log('Testing') in beforeSend and on always console.log('TestingDone') is shown on console but the loader is not shown up @Ben

Comment: I have seen in console there is an line [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. like this is this an error that's why loader is not loader or any other issue @Ben

Comment: Nope that shouldn't prevent it from showing, you still got the console log so the code is being invoked. Try some of these other methods of showing the loader - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76446/how-to-implement-loader-widget-in-magento2 - I'm not sure where there are so many. If none of them work then it sounds like there is a problem with your theme.

Comment: Thanks for your response will you please tell me is there anything which i have to add on define(
[
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/url-builder',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/error-processor',
    'mage/url'
] like loader or jquery/ui and thanks for the link i will follow that @Ben

Comment: Nope, you only need to do that if you are using the jQuery loader widget. It's yet another method you could try, only Magento could add so many ways to show a simple spinner - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_loader.html

Answer (score 0):

In code when you want to show loader, put this code :

```
showLoader: true
```

Comment: I have added this in $.ajax({
                url: urlFormatter.build(url),
                data: JSON.stringify(payload),
                global: false,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                type: 'PUT',
                async: false,
               showLoader: true
            }) this code but it doesn't show loader i have added loader on define too.but doesn't seems show. @Dhiren

Comment: Any error on console?

Comment: Yes it shows [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience @Dhiren Will You please help.